# Multiple commands produce OpenSSL.xcframework when using React Native Flipper

Tags: ios, react-native, fbflipper

I already have an OpenSSL framework added to my Xcode workspace. Env (Xcode 12.5, React-native 0.65.1)

When I add Flipper, I get the below error as Flipper-Folly is also creating an Openssl framework

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyMobileApp-Dev.app/Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework':

Target 'MyMobileApp' has copy command from '/Users/amit/Desktop/MQ/Src/ios/OpenSSL.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/OpenSSL.framework' to '/Users/amit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyMobileApp-Dev.app/Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework'
That command depends on the command in Target 'MyMobileApp': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
```

If I remove flipper it works fine.
Is there a way to remove OpenSSL from the flipper, as I would definitely like to use its features for debugging?